# Can I rule out moderation with stable regression coefficients?

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction

I have a multiple linear regression, with a and b as independent and c and dependend variables. I want to rule out a moderating effect between a and b. To do that in the easiest way, my idea was to simply run the regression twice, one time with a and b and one time only with a, leaving out b. 
I can now compare the regression coefficients of a in both models. If they do not change, moderation can be rules out.

Can I make this conclusion? Even if in both cases the Modell itself is significant, but the coefficient for a isn't?

Comment: The literature suggests a moderation effect. But between a and b I could not find correlation in my data. So what I want is to rule out that there is a moderation effect.

Answer (score 1):

You may have misunderstood what moderation is, since you didn't mention an interaction between A and B on C. What you have described is the process of figuring out whether the inclusion of B in a linear model of C on A *changes the estimate of the coefficient on A*. Moderation is substantive: does the effect of A on C depend on an *individual's* level of B? One question is about the nature of estimating coefficients, the other is about the relationship between variables *in the world*.

If the estimate of the coefficient on A changes based on whether B is in the model or not, then there is a correlation between A and B that may be result of confounding (in which B is a common cause of A and C) or mediation (in which B is caused at least partly by A). Neither of these (necessarily) involve moderation.

To test for moderation, that is, to test whether the effect of A depends on *an individual's* level of B, you need to specify a single model as follows: $Y = b_o + b_1 A + b_2 B + b_3 A B + \epsilon$. The significance of the test for $b_3$ tests whether moderation is present, with the null hypothesis being that it is absent.

Comment: So what I did was the wrong idea, that explains why I couldn't find proof of that in the literature. I just thought it would be a different way of ruling out moderation, specially because I only have 250 observations and the coefficients are likly to be insignificant. But I do understand it right, that correlation between a and b is a necessary condition for a moderating effect? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: A and B do not need to be correlated to find a moderating effect. Consider randomly assigning males and females to a weight training experiment. You randomly assigned, so sex is uncorrelated with experimental condition, but the effect of the weight training condition might depend on one's sex. That is moderation without correlation.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way to look for moderation is to look at the interaction. You could run the following regressions (in order), and compare the coefficient of determination (R^2) for each:

c = a
c = a, b
c = a, b, a*b

Most statistical software will let you do this and will provide an F statistic for the change in R^2 at each step. If the change when you add b is significant, then b significantly adds to your ability to predict c. If the change is significant when you add a*b, then you have moderation.

David A. Kenney provides a [good explanation of moderation](http://davidakenny.net/cm/moderation.htm).

Comment: You don't need to do tests for changes in $R^2$; the coefficient on $b$ in the second model and the coefficient on the interaction in the third model are equivalent to change in $R^2$ tests and are produced automatically.

Comment: Good point. Just want to highlight that this is true only if you are adding only one predictor at a time (which is the situation as described in this case).
Most software will produce the change in R^2 stats automatically if you enter all of the equations at once.